Using MiKTeX and TeXstudio - can't produce a working bibliography or diagnose the problem with my code
I'm using TeXstudio for the first time and am trying to create my first bibliography using the inbuilt Biblatex package. Every time I try to build the .tex file, however, I get the following errors on my log and am unsure how to resolve them. The lines referred to in the errors are not the corresponding lines in either my .tex or .bib files.
The errors:

The .tex code:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\title{CO31 – Numerical Analysis of White Dwarf Mass-Radius Relation}
\author{James Kennedy, univ5653}
\date{June 2024}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    here is some text \cite{REF1}
    
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{references}
\end{document}

The .bib code (in a file references.bib)
\usepackage{url}

@misc{REF1,
    author = {{University of Oxford}},
    title = {C{O}31: Structure of {W}hite {D}warf {S}tars},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www-teaching.physics.ox.ac.uk/practical_course/scripts/srv/local/rscripts/trunk/Computing/CO31/CO31.pdf}},
    year = {2020},
    month = {October},
}

@misc{REF2,
    author = {{University of Oxford}},
    title = {Oxford {P}hysics: {T}hird {Y}ear {A}strophysics (B3) {S}tellar {S}tructure and {E}volution},
    howpublished = {\url{https://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/~podsi/lec_mm03.html}},
    year = {2006},
}


When I compile your example, I don't get the same error messages. Moreover, you should really do at least \usepackage{biblatex} and \addbibresource.

Reproduce  this small examples step to setp to realize of any mistake with your attempts.

\usepackage{url} needs to go into your .tex file, bit the .bib file

your document is not using biblatex but the classic bibtex system, use an option to use pdflatex+bibtex not pdflatex/biblatex+biber

The only problem I can see with your code is that indeed the \usepackage{url} should not be in the .bib file (where it will be ignored), but in the preamble of your .tex file, as samcarter says. You might want to go for \usepackage{hyperref} instead of \usepackage{url} while you're there so you get clickable links as well.

Oh of course that seems obvious in retrospect - I swapped the \usepackage{url} line to the .tex file and all is working now. Thanks for the help!
